# Contact Form 7 dom manipulation

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dom, user-input, contact-form-7

Im trying to create price calculator for my form, but im having some serious problems on getting the values from  -fields.
Here's the basic .js Code:

```
document.getElementsByName('numberOfThings').value
```

It seems that CF7 doesn't really pass new values to the -fields "value" -attribute, because console outputs only "undefined" as response for the call.

I've also noticed that basic

```
document.getElementById('textFieldId').innerHTML;
```

doesn't get the data from  -elements.

Any suggestions how to work this around?

Thanks!

Comment: use `document.getElementById('textFieldId').value;`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I did not know there were such a difference between getElementById and getElementsByName. Sorry for the "unclear or not usefull question".

Comment: getElementByName is get elements by name, but the element of name. For example: `var collection=getElementByName('div');` (element name should be a html element name). getElementsById is get the element by it's id attribute. `<input id="abc" />` and then `getElementById('abc');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay you can access the forms like this:

```
user_input = document.forms[0].text.value
```

where text is the name of the text field, textarea or hidden field. The value of this element gives the text, so we transfer it to user_input.

Writing is also possible:

```
document.forms[0].text.value = 'The new value';
```